# Make container div expand to size of inner contents using table-cell display

Tags: html, css

Seems like this is a pretty standard problem: I need a container `div` element to expand horizontally according to the `width` property of the inner `fieldset`. Everything I've found so far offers two solutions.

First solution is to use `display:inline-block`. However, I'm using `display:table-cell` to position the container so this won't work.

The second is to add a `min-width` to the container div. This does solve the issue, however the `width` of the inner `fieldset` will not be static, so while it looks fine when there's a lot of content in the `fieldset` it looks awkward otherwise (there is a huge gap between this particular `div` and the one to it's right).

Is there another way to force the container `div` to automatically resize, based on inner content, without using the two solutions above?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mj3h1682/

**EDIT**

Added the following script to the page. Would like a method using `css`, however if anyone knows of one.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var width = $('#Profile').outerWidth() + 20;
        $('#partialColumn1').css('min-width', width);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: use Jquery to increase the width